# Java Android create a view in FrameLayout

Tags: java, android, android-framelayout

Hi I want to create a view which look like this : [image]

But now I have this

[image]

and this is my xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="pl..smok.ui.activity.SettingsActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_bar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/change_orieientation_screen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_bar_container"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:clickable="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Zmień orientację ekranu"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't know how I can create a line in center, and inline rectangle and a rectangle have two imageView.

Comment: can i get asset

Comment: @RakshithKumar what you want ?

Comment: okay no need, i will provide you entire UI in some time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please look into this UI, I think it will be helpful for you

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/dummy"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

       <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

> please add below code into drawable folder as a "dummy.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ffffffff"/>

    <stroke android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#ff000000" />

    <padding android:left="1dp"
        android:top="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp" />

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: You don't have to specify `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView` manually. `ImageView` is automatically resolved to that by AppCompat inflater.

Comment: Yes agree... this is only sample

Comment: Exactly, keep it as simple as possible, please.

Comment: Ok but how I can delete a line beetwen two imageView ?

Comment: Yea i will do that one also, wait for some min

Comment: Its my pleasure